# MVC Response.Redirect not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-ajax

I have a method inside MVC Controller which is called from href inside anchor tag.

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(string value)
{
    if(true)
    {
        return new RedirectResult("http://google.com");
    }
}
```

when I debug and hit that method Response.Redirect does nothing no exceptions either. any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd have probably expected that would work, but normally you'd use one of the `return Redirect` methods inside the controller to redirect from the controller.

Comment: Found an error in browser debugger XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://google.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://gmpmss.localhost:3333' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: That's very strange, that's the security measure added to prevent unauthorized cross site AJAX requests - not sure why Response.Redirect from the server side would cause that!!

Comment: it is expected. Ajax request gets redirected to third-party site (google in this case) and gets failed by browser since Google does not specify headers to allow ajax requests from this site. This question lacks some details. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Server side redirects aren't AJAX requests, but I've just remembered why - in debug mode Visual Studio injects a JavaScript debug helper onto the page, which is then blocked when you redirect to Google.

Comment: do you know a way to get around that?

Comment: Personally I just disable the JS debugger, it causes more problems than it solves! You should stop using Response.Redirect in MVC anyway though.

Comment: I am using VS 2013 do you know a quick way of disabling JS debugger?

Answer (score 4):

Use `Redirect`

```
return Redirect("http://www.google.com");
```

`Response.Redirect` is not preferred way of doing redirects in asp.net mvc

**[Response.Redirect and ASP.NET MVC – Do Not Mix](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/01/response-redirect-and-asp-net-mvc-do-not-mix.aspx)**

Update: It seems that you are trying to redirect ajax request. If you redirect ajax request, your main page won't be redirected.

Comment: this method requires return type of string

Comment: then you need to refactor that method.

Comment: public ActionResult DoSomething(string value)
{
    if(true)
    {
        return new RedirectResult("http://google.com");
    }
}

Just did this and still doesn't work

Comment: please add some details about what are you trying to do. Why are you trying to redirect your ajax request to google?

Comment: google is just an example site. I've created an anchor tag which calls the method <a id="anchor" href="/Controller/DoSomething"> and from that method I wanna redirect to a client site

Comment: See my comment on the main - it's the Visual Studio JavaScript debug helper that's causing the AJAX error.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you need to do here to avoid all these issues.

Starting with the AJAX errors you're getting, they most like relate to the javascript debugger, which Microsoft refer to as "BrowserLink".

If you use Firefox or Chrome, this feature simply doesn't work, which is probably the easiest way to avoid the issue, however you can disable the feature here:

[image: Visual Studio 2013 - Browser Link]

You can change the default browser to run the website in just to the left.

---

In terms of `Response.Redirect`, I think that's been well covered, you should use `return Redirect()` instead, however your code needs to be refactored to allow for that.

Assuming that method is a helper method which is required to be separate from the controller itself, there are a couple of main approaches to doing what you're trying to to do.

**1) Magic Values**

This could include "`redirect1`" or also commonly `null`, and would look something like:

```
public ActionResult MyAction
{
    string data = ProcessString("some data");

    if (data == null) { return Redirect("google.com"); }
}

public string ProcessString(string input)
{
    if (condition) { return null; }
    string output = input + "!"; // or whatever you need to do!
    return input;
}
```

**2) Handle via exceptions**

Assuming the problem is that the data is in some way bad, and you want to redirect away because you cant process it, Exception handling is most likely the way to go. It also allows for different types of exceptions to be raised by a single method and handled independently without having magic values which then can't be used as normal data.

```
public ActionResult MyAction
{
    string data; // remember this will be null, not "" by default

    try
    {
        data = ProcessString("some data");
    }
    catch (OwlMisalignedException ex)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error", new { exData = ex.Code });
    }

    // proceed with controller as normal
}

public string ProcessString(string input)
{
    if (condition) 
    {
        throw new OwlMisalignedException(1234);
        // this is (obviously) a made up exception with a Code property 
        // as an example of passing the error code back up to an error 
        // handling page, for example.
    }

    string output = input + "!"; // or whatever you need to do!
    return input;
}
```

By using that approach you can effectively add extra return states to methods without having to fiddle with your return type or create loads of magic values.

Don't use `throw Exception` - either use one of the more specific types `ArgumentException` and `ArgumentNullException` will probably come in handy, or create your own types if needs be.

You'll find info on creating your own Exception types on here easily enough.

Comment: I disabled BrowserLink and I don't see XMLHttpRequest cannot load exception anymore. I tried refactoring my method like you suggested still it doesn't work and I have exception handling implemented but it doesn't catch anything :/

Comment: If you could update your question with both your refactored controller action and helper method, I'm sure we can help. It should just be something basic now.